# Visual Studio "Start xslt debugging" option not visible

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xslt

I am editing an xlst file and I cannot run it. How do I do that? Under "XML" I can only see "Create Schemas"(unclickable) and "Schemas". There should be an option to start xslt with or without debugging.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is plausible that you're running version of Visual Studio where XSLT debugging feature is not made available. See [MSDN: Debugging XSLT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255605.aspx) :

> *"XSLT debugging is available in the **Visual Studio Team System** and the **Professional Edition**."*

<sub>I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition in my personal laptop and it doesn't have XSLT debugging menu. At the same time, my work laptop has Visual Studio 2012 installed, Professional Edition if I remember correctly, and it indeed has the XSLT debugging menu available.</sub>

Comment: I have passed enableDebug = true in the constructor and I have VS2017 Enterprise. I see a XML menu on top, but it does not have the "Start xslt debugging" entry.

Answer (score 8):

Like says in https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms255603.aspx, you must use the `XslCompiledTransform` class and enable debug mode in the constructor parameters.

Now when you will debug your application, VS will break on your breakpoints in your xlst file.

```
var xsl = new XslCompiledTransform(enableDebug :true);
xsl.Load("transform.xslt");

var reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.xml");

var outputPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(outputPath))
{
    xsl.Transform(reader, null, stream);
}
```

Comment: Nice! Works in CE.

Comment: Thanks, works great. One thing: `XmlDocument doc` isn't actually necessary.

Comment: Confirmed working in 2017 CE and no need of XmlDocument doc. Thanks.

Comment: I have passed enableDebug = true in the constructor and I have VS2017 Enterprise. I see a XML menu on top, but it does not have the "Start xslt debugging" entry.

Comment: As far as I know (Didn't test it for years), they are no "Start xslt debugging". You only have to start debugging your app. And when the program call xsl.Transform, it should break in the xml file